# Prove that the sequence $a_n$ of positive numbers such that $a_n=\sqrt {a_ {n-1}a_ {n-2}} $, $n>2$ converges. Find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Here according to given condition $a_2$ shouldn't exist as $a_1$ and $a_0$ do not exist, which makes the existence of entire sequence dubious. Please someone correct where I'm wrong.

Comment: Please edit your post to make your formula readable and inside the text, *not only in the title*.

Comment: Since the relation is for $n>2,$ the two first terms $a_1$ and $a_2$ are supposed to exist.